# Angular 2 AsynPipe isn't working with an Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, reactive-programming, rxjs, observable

I'm getting the following error:

```
EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' in [files | async in Images@1:9]
```

Here's the relevant part of the template:

```
<img *ngFor="#file of files | async" [src]="file.path">
```

Here's my code:

```
export class Images {
  public files: any; 
  public currentPage: number = 0;
  private _rawFiles: any;

  constructor(public imagesData: ImagesData) {
    this.imagesData = imagesData;  
    this._rawFiles = this.imagesData.getData()
        .flatMap(data => Rx.Observable.fromArray(data.files));
    this.nextPage();
  }

  nextPage() {
    let imagesPerPage = 10;
    this.currentPage += 1;
    this.files = this._rawFiles
                    .skip((this.currentPage - 1) * imagesPerPage)
                    .take(imagesPerPage);
    console.log("this.files:", this.files);                
  }
}
```

The `console.log` at the end shows that it's an observable:

[image: last console.log]

`this.imagesData.getData()` return a regular RxJS observable from Angular's `Http` service, so why wouldn't async pipe work with it? Maybe the way I'm using `flatMap()` is wrong and it messes something up?

If I try to subscribe to this observable like that:

```
this.files = this._rawFiles
                .skip((this.currentPage - 1) * imagesPerPage)
                .take(imagesPerPage)
                .subscribe(file => {
                  console.log("file:", file);
                });
```

It prints a list of objects as expected:

[image]

Comment: `*ngFor` only iterates over  an array, not a series of events therefore your `Observable` needs to return an array instead of a series of objects.

Comment: I'd go for an `Observable<File[]>` using the `scan` operator.

Comment: See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6392

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with an `Observable<File[]>` instead:

```
this.files = this._rawFiles
         .skip((this.currentPage - 1) * imagesPerPage)
         .take(imagesPerPage)
         .map(file => [file])
         .startWith([])
         .scan((acc,value) => acc.concat(value))
```

This should require no manual code to `subscribe` and should work perfectly with your current template.

I do something very similar in [this blog post.](http://lukajcb.github.io/blog/angular2/2016/04/02/frp-in-angular-2.html)

Comment: Thanks. It works, although it's not exactly pretty. I'm already receiving an array from server and only converting it to a stream to be able to use RxJS's utility methods (`skip` and `take`). If I have to convert to array every time like that, it would be easier to not use RxJS for the array manipulation altogether