# Convert a plain string[] into a Observable<string[]> and concat it to another Observable<string[]> using RxJS 5

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I am trying to convert a plain `string[]` into a `Observable<string[]>` and concat it to an existing `Observable<string[]>`.

I will then use an angular2 `async` pipe in order to display the `Observable`.

Here is my code:

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/Rx';


@Injectable()
export class AppService {

    constructor() {
        console.log('constructor', 'appService');
        this.constructSomeObservable();
    }

    someObservable$:Observable <string[]>;

    constructSomeObservable() {
        this.someObservable$ = Observable.create(observer => {
            const eventSource = new EventSource('/interval-sse-observable');
            eventSource.onmessage = x => observer.next(JSON.parse(x.data));
            eventSource.onerror = x => observer.error(console.log('EventSource failed'));
            return () => {
                eventSource.close();
            };
        });

        this.someObservable$.subscribe(
            theStrings=> {
                console.log(theStrings);
                //Somehow convert the plain array of strings to an observable and concat it to this.someObservable$ observable...
            },
            error=>console.log(error)
        );
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Furthermore, I want to ensure that the service instance `Observable<string[]>` is continuously updated as the EventSource is called repeatedly. Is my subscribe logic in the right place?

**edit 1**: I tried to use RxJS `concat` operator as follows:

```
    this.someObservable$.subscribe(
        theStrings=> {
            console.log(theStrings);
            this.someObservable$ = this.someObservable$.concat(Observable.create(theStrings));
        },
        error=>console.log(error)
    );
 }
```

together with the angular2 `async` pipe:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="#s of appService.someObservable$ | async">
       a string: {{ s }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

and nothing gets displayed on the page; the strings just get displayed on the console...

What I am getting wrong?

**edit 2**: The app is available on github [here](https://github.com/balteo/demo-angular2-rxjs)

**edit 3**: I have taken into account Thierry's advice, especially the use of the `async` pipe in order to subscribe as well as the usage of the scan operator.

The only remaining issue now is that I need to click on the router link in order for the strings to render on the template... The template does not update automatically...

See project on github and relevant tag: https://github.com/balteo/demo-angular2-rxjs/tree/36864628/536299

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would leverage the `scan` operator to do that. Here is a sample:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app'
  template: `
    <div>
      <div *ngFor="#elt of someObservable$  | async">{{elt.name}</div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.someObservable$ = Observable.create((observer) => {
      const eventSource = new EventSource('/interval-sse-observable');
      eventSource.onmessage = x => observer.next(JSON.parse(x.data));
      eventSource.onerror = x => observer.error(console.log('EventSource failed'));
      return () => {
        eventSource.close();
      };
    })
    .startWith([])
    .scan((acc,value) => acc.concat(value));
  }
}
```

Here is the corresponding plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/St7LozX3bnOBcoHaG4uM?p=preview.

See this question for more details:

- [Angular 2 AsynPipe isn't working with an Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36686465/angular-2-asynpipe-isnt-working-with-an-observable)

Comment: Thanks Thierry! As regards the async pipe and the article you suggested, I do have an `Observable<string[]>` so it should be OK. Now regarding the rest of the code and your plunker, I am surprised I don't require to subscribe. How come?

Comment: You're welcome! In fact, the `async` pipe subscribes transparently (and unsubscribe) for you ;-)

Comment: Yes not so obvious actually ;-) See https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/common/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L75

Comment: I have updated my post. I have one remaining issue (related to the router) that I cannot reproduce in your plunker.

Comment: I guess I'll open another post as it is not the same issue. Marking as accepted.

Comment: Okay. Yes don't hesitate ;-)