# How can I append items to Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

How do I append items to `Observable`?

This is some code:

```
 this.logEntries = this.controllerService.getLog(this.controller.remoteID, this.skip, this.max);

        this.logEntries.subscribe(a => {
            this.allLogEntries.add(this.logEntries)
        });
```

and here is their declarations:

```
 logEntries: Observable<Log[]>;
    allLogEntries: Observable<Log[]> = Observable.empty<Log[]>();
```

I want to append items to allLogEntries as they are being fetched from the web service. How do I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps the `scan` operator could interest you. Here is a sample:

```
obs.startWith([])
 .scan((acc,value) => acc.concat(value))
 .subscribe((data) => {
   console.log(data);
 });
```

See this question for more details:

- [Angular 2 Updating objects in “real time.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006264/angular-2-updating-objects-in-real-time/37006432#37006432)

Comment: now (2023) you've got to `import  {scan} from 'rxjs';` and `... .pipe(scan((acc,value) => acc.concat(value)).subscribe(...)`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject):

It's an `Observable` where you can push a new item as containing object.

Comment: Looks right but could you please help me to write the code for this. This is so confusing.

Comment: Even this declaration is not working allLogEntries: BehaviorSubject<Log[]> = BehaviorSubject.empty<Log[]>(); It gives syntax error. How do I create empty BehaviorSubject?

Comment: @TimLiberty you don't, it's empty by default until you push something into it. Please edit the question to clarify what you're doing, what your inputs are, what you've tried and what precisely has gone wrong.

Comment: The above solution would intimate all its subscriber once `.onNext` method is called. It is not going to store the value as in array inside its instance..

Comment: @jonrsharpe: How could it be empty? Wouldn't it be null?

Comment: @tim a regular Subject can just be created with nothing. A BehaviourSubject needs an *initial value*, it can't be empty. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md. Again, please **edit the question**, where are your inputs coming from? Do you actually have two observable sources?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Thanks. But what if I don't have the initial value? Sorry this is really pretty confusing.

Comment: @tim then you can't use a behaviour subject. Have you read my answer? A subject might not be what you want. Don't just keep saying it's confusing, do the research.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I have one data coming from my data service as observable using angular2. Now I want to append it to my master list which can be of observable / BehaviorSubject etc. This is a typical case of pagination. I load some records initially then load some more and want to append it to my master list.

Comment: @TimLiberty then don't you just want a list on the instance *outside* of the observable, that you can append to each time the observable gets new data? You don't want to append to the observable, you want to append the observable to something else? One last time: **EDIT THE QUESTION**.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I don't know what is the issue here since I am new to RXJS. I will just do what I understand so far in few minutes and will notify you here once done. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to join two observables together, you need to e.g. [`combineLatest`](http://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest):

```
Observable
  .combineLatest(this.logEntries, this.allLogEntries)
  .subscribe(...);
```

This gives you access to the latest values from each observable, updated as either of them change, and you can combine them as needed.

---

If you want to be able to manually push entries into one of the source observables, make it a [`Subject`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md):

```
this.logEntries = new Subject();
Observable
  .combineLatest(this.logEntries, this.allLogEntries)
  .subscribe(...);
```

then you can invoke an update with:

```
this.logEntries.next(...);
```

and your subscription will receive the new `logEntries` along with the most recent `allLogEntries`. Depending on the behaviour you want, you can use a `ReplaySubject` or `BehaviourSubject` instead of the vanilla `Subject`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have pasted the whole component code. Let me know if this helps or you need more info. *allLogEntries: Subject<Log[]> = Subject.empty<Log[]>(); * is not compiling. Should it be Subject / BehaviorSubject / simple array or what. Just need something that works :). I will read your answer as well now.

Comment: @tim that doesn't explain why `allLogEntries` is an observable. Why don't you just make it an array, holding everything so far (starting as an empty array)? I've told you why your method of creating an empty subject doesn't work; this answer shows how to actually do that. Thus far it seems like you're asking exactly the wrong question, in which case answering that question won't help you.

Comment: Seems okay. Let me try with plain array.

Comment: @tim it would be helpful to explain more broadly what you're trying to do and why within your questions, otherwise we end up with Xy problems http://xyproblem.info