# Why doesn't my Angular page refresh when using an EventEmitter?

Tags: angular, typescript, eventemitter

My angular SPA doesn't refresh when my EventEmitter emits an event.

Here is my `EventEmitter` in the child component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Todo } from '../todo';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-todo',
  templateUrl: './add-todo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-todo.component.css']
})
export class AddTodoComponent implements OnInit {
  newTodo: Todo = new Todo();

  @Output() addTodoEvent: EventEmitter<Todo> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  addTodo() {
    this.addTodoEvent.emit(this.newTodo);
    console.log('event emitted');
    this.newTodo = new Todo();
    console.log('new todo created');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Here is the template that consumes it:

```
<div class="container">
  <app-add-todo (addTodoEvent)='onAddTodo($event)'></app-add-todo>
   // other template stuff
</div>
```

Here is the declaration of `onAddTodo`:

```
  onAddTodo(todo: Todo) {
    console.log('onAddTodo called');
    this.todoDataService.addTodo(todo);
  }
```

Basically, the application works, but I have to hit F5 to refresh the page after any change is made.

One thing to note is that this used to work when I was using an array as a data source, but when I went to json-server and Observables, the page stopped refreshing.

I'm happy to supply any further information that may be needed.

UPDATE:

Here's `addTodo`:

```
  addTodo(todo: Todo): void {
    this.aHttpService.post<Todo>(`http://localhost:3000/todos`, todo).subscribe(
      val => {
        console.log('POST call successful value returned in body', val);
      },
      response => {
        console.log('POST call in error', response);
      },
      () => {
        console.log('The POST observable is now completed.');
      }
    );
  }
```

The full code to list the todos is as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Todo } from '../todo';
import { TodoDataService } from '../todo-data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo-list',
  templateUrl: './todo-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo-list.component.css']
})
export class TodoListComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private todoDataService: TodoDataService) {}

  completetodos: Observable<Array<Todo>>;
  incompletetodos: Observable<Array<Todo>>;

  onAddTodo(todo: Todo) {
    console.log('onAddTodo called');
    this.todoDataService.addTodo(todo);
  }

  toggleTodoComplete(todo) {
    this.todoDataService.toggleTodoComplete(todo);
  }

  removeTodo(todo) {
    this.todoDataService.deleteTodoById(todo.id);
  }

  editTodo(todo: Todo) {
    todo.editMode = true;
  }

  updateTodo(todo: Todo, editInput) {
    todo.title = editInput.value;
    todo.editMode = false;
    this.todoDataService.updateTodoById(todo.id, todo);
  }

  allTasks(): Observable<Array<Todo>> {
    return this.todoDataService.getAllTodos();
  }

  completedTodos(): Observable<Array<Todo>> {
    return this.todoDataService.completedTodos();
  }

  incompletedToDos(): Observable<Array<Todo>> {
    return this.todoDataService.incompletedTodos();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.completetodos = this.completedTodos();
    this.incompletetodos = this.incompletedToDos();
  }
}
```

Comment: addTodo is executing an Http call?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky -- Added my `addToDo` call.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to figure out with piecemeal snippets of code like this, and apparent typos (you have an EventEmitter named 'addTodoEvent', but a call to 'add.emit'). A complete running example, perhaps on stackblitz.com would help a lot.

Comment: You need to please clarify what you are expecting to have updated on the screen after the post(). Are you pushing the new Todo to an array after post success or anything for display in a view or anything?

Comment: @NickHodges can u pls post your code where list the todos?

Comment: @JameelM  -- Thanks for helping:  Added the template.

Comment: Okay, it's hard to provide a StackBlitz of *my* code, because it requires the API server.  

If it is any help, the current state of my project is here:

https://github.com/NickHodges/Angular-TodoApp

Here is the original code that I used, which does indeed update with every event:

https://stackblitz.com/github/ImanDB/Angular-TodoApp

Comment: @NickHodges I mean component code where creating the todo list by listening the emitted event

Comment: @JameelM -- thanks again.  I included the component code.

Comment: @NickHodges Updated my answer a little bit , if you use BehaviorSubject , things will become little bit easy for you

Comment: Thanks to everyone -- I got it working.  The trick was that, as mentioned, the actual array's had to be changed, not just the items in them.  (I switched the storage to arrays).  It was a tough call as to which answer to accept, both were very useful.  Thanks again for the assist.  I'm grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are done with the successful save of the todo , You have to update the observables

```
 onAddTodo(todo: Todo) {
this.todoDataService.addTodo(todo).subscribe(
      val => {
         // here you have to update the observables //incompletetodos.next(newTodo)
      },
      response => {
        console.log('POST call in error', response);
      },
      () => {
        console.log('The POST observable is now completed.');
      }
    );
}
```

Also you don't need to subscribe here

```
 addTodo(todo: Todo): void {
    return this.aHttpService.post<Todo>(`http://localhost:3000/todos`, todo);
  }
```

I think push won't work for observables , You can refer the below link to append a new item in to the incompletetodos observable array

[How can I append items to Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719237/how-can-i-append-items-to-observable)

If you would use BehaviorSubject(another type of observable) instead of Observable , you can easily add a new item. Something like below

```
incompletetodos: BehaviorSubject<Array<Todo>> = BehaviorSubject.empty<Array<Todo>>();
```

//you can push a new item like below

```
 incompletetodos.next(newTodo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your service should return the observable like this:

```
 addTodo(todo: Todo): void {
    return this.aHttpService.post<Todo>(`http://localhost:3000/todos`, todo);
 }
```

And using it in the component like this:

```
 onAddTodo(todo: Todo) {
    this.todoDataService.addTodo(todo).subscribe(val => {
       this.incompletetodos.push(val);
    });;
 }
```

(I minimized the code)

---

Reference: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#add-a-new-hero

*src/app/heroes/heroes.component.ts (add)*

```
add(name: string): void {
  name = name.trim();
  if (!name) { return; }
  this.heroService.addHero({ name } as Hero)
    .subscribe(hero => {
      this.heroes.push(hero);
    });
}
```

*src/app/hero.service.ts (addHero)*

```
/** POST: add a new hero to the server */
addHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
  return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions).pipe(
    tap((hero: Hero) => this.log(`added hero w/ id=${hero.id}`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<Hero>('addHero'))
  );
}
```

---

> Why doesn't my Angular page refresh when using an EventEmitter?

You might think this way, we're using Angular to build a single page application which doesn't cause any full page refresh, we just update a part of the website.

> Basically, the application works, but I have to hit F5 to refresh the
>   page after any change is made.

Because whenever you hit F5, your Angular application well be re-initialized which fires this lifecycle hook:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.completetodos = this.completedTodos();
    this.incompletetodos = this.incompletedToDos();
}
```

Therefore, your application reflects the up-to-date data of the database.

> One thing to note is that this used to work when I was using an array
>   as a data source, but when I went to json-server and Observables, **the**
>   **page stopped refreshing**.

In fact, when you're using an array as a data source, our application doesn't refresh at all. That's something call *data-binding*, the data which we see on the UI is bound to the data which the Angular application holding (on client-side, in client's memory).

When communicating with the server, when we make some changes in the server's database, we have to update our client's data based on the response from the server. This is how we'll do in this case, in your Todo App.