# http toPromise return an object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise, rxjs

I have the function below:

```
getUser(userId: string) : Observable<any> {
    var getUserURL = `/api/users/${userId}`,
        getUserStatus = this.getUserStatus();


    return this.http.get<any>(getUserURL).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('getUser - Get User failed', null))
    );
  }
```

This returns the data from response from REST API for this URL `/api/users/${userId}` to toPromise

Is there any way that I can return the object that include the response data from REST API + local data(getUserStatus) which is Boolean in this case.
Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify why you need it to be a `Promise<T>` instead of an `Observable<T>`? How do you intend to use the response?

Comment: Looks like the question is how to append data to `Observable` and return `REST API + local data(getUserStatus)` after subscribing. Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719237/how-can-i-append-items-to-observable

Answer (score 2):

Your request is not returning a Promise unless it isn't included in your example.  You have an Observable.

Assuming I understand your question correctly.  If you want to return the HTTP response + the local status you would do something like this using piped operators:

**Service**

```
getUser(userId: string) : Observable<any> {
  const path = `/api/users/${userId}`
  const userStatus = this.getUserStatus();

  return this.http.get<any>(path)
    .pipe(
      map((response: any) => {
        return { response, userStatus };
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError('[USER]::getUser Failed', null))
    );
}
```

**Component**

```
this.getUser(1000).subscribe(({response, userStatus}) => { 
  // Handle response and status
  console.log('RESPONSE', response);
  console.log('USER_STATUS', userStatus);
});
```

Comment: That's great @kim.  If the solution is correct on StackOverflow you can mark is as the chosen answer using the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

Like @mtputlz said you're returning an Observable. If you want to return your reponse which is in your case a boolean. Then we can convert the obserable to a promise:

```
async getUser(userId: string) : any {
    var getUserURL = `/api/users/${userId}`,
        getUserStatus = this.getUserStatus();


    return await this.http.get<any>(getUserURL).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('getUser - Get User failed', null))
    ).toPromise();
  }
```